# compile node with --harmony-generators on by default

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-harmony

I'm trying to build node v0.11.12-release with the `--harmony-generators` flag defaulted to always on.  I thought I'd be able edit [this line](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.11.12-release/deps/v8/src/flag-definitions.h#L179) to have the value `true`, but when I do that I get the below error whenever I run node.

`Extension or internal compilation error.
Segmentation fault: 11`

line I tried to edit: deps/v8/src/flag-definitions.h

`DEFINE_bool(harmony_generators, true, "enable harmony generators")`

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/tjfontaine/node-setflags ? looks like a better (in many ways) idea

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that, but I'm really looking to compile node with support defaulted to true.  My next best bet is to alias it, but I really want it compiled with the default set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliasing sounds like a better idea, but if you are sure that's what you want you can set some v8 flags with `configure` script:

```
./configure --v8-options="--harmony-generators"
```

Comment: woah, that's not in v0.11.12-release, but I'll take it!  Worked on master.  Thanks!